# Socket Handshake in Android < 5.0 (Lollipop) with TLSv1.2 problem

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I use below code to create a socket to server and get server public key (Server TLS version is 1.2).
The problem is in Android < 5.0 at `socket.startHandshake();`

```
catch error : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer.
```

I searched many and find I have to force Android < 5 to use TLSv1.2, but I can't do this ([+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877125/enable-tls-1-2-in-android-4-4), [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202267/android-4-1-to-4-4-kitkat-enable-tls-1-2-for-api?noredirect=1&lq=1), [+](https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/)).

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname, 443);
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
socket.startHandshake();
Certificate[] certs = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
Certificate cert = certs[0];
PublicKey serverKey = cert.getPublicKey();

CertificateFactory cf      = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream        caInput = context.getResources().getAssets().open("filename.cert");
Certificate        ca;
ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

if (String.valueOf(serverKey).equals(String.valueOf(ca.getPublicKey()))) {
     My codes ...
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should force TLSv1.2 on Android KitKat and below like so:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Cheers!

Comment: I do this but this error happened: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
12-22 11:54:26.970 3741-3762/ir.refahotp.refahotp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
12-22 11:54:26.970 3741-3762/ir.refahotp.refahotp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)`

Comment: Which android version are you running it on? Take note that v1.2 is supported on Android 4.1+ (JellyBean) only.

Comment: Everything on server is ok

Comment: I use Android 4.4

Comment: Can you confirm that the issue is not caused by any of the following:
1. The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown
2. The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed
3. The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have to downgrade server SSL to TLSv1 and problem fixed.