# Fetch request with https url is not working for Android<5.0

Tags: react-native

In my project fetch request with https is not working for Android<5.0. I know it's for ssl certificate issue. But I don't know how to add or solve that problem. So far I tried many things by googling the problem.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solid solution to this issue. I had the same issue and I have tried it and it still doesn't work in old samsung devices. The android devices which are equal and below 5.0 use TLS 1.1 or 1.0. The new standard TLS is 1.2. Even tho TLS 1.2 exists in Android devices below 5.0 they are not enabled by default. So you have to enable it manually by changing socket so when your app loads it should enable TLS 1.2 in old devices. The certificate of Android<5.0 devices has been issued before TLS 1.2 introduced. Below are useful links so good luck with trying it.

[Android 4.1 to 4.4 KitKat - Enable TLS 1.2 for API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202267/android-4-1-to-4-4-kitkat-enable-tls-1-2-for-api)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7192