# Android KitKat does not support TLSv1.2

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, tls1.2

I am testing my app on older devices, as we are targeting the developing market and expect users to have older, pre-lollipop, devices.

I use `RetroFit (2.6.4)` and `OkHttp (3.12.4)` to communicate with the REST server, which is hosted on Amazon. AWS supports TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 but we have it locked to TLSv1.2 in our `NodeJS` server.

The app works for new devices but I get the following error on KitKat:

```
<-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_CCM_8_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.2]
```

If you look at the end of that error message, it says:

```
, tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.2]
```

So I think I have the correct code there to enable TLSv1.2 but I'm not using it correctly, and OKHttp is trying to use SSLv3 or TLS1 instead of TLSv1.2.

Also, I just checked our server on SSLLabs and it supports the following TLSv1.2 cipher suites:

```
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256
```

Full stacktrace:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_CCM_8_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.2]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectionSpecSelector.configureSecureSocket(ConnectionSpecSelector.java:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:313)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:284)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:225)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:104)
```

I'm using a custom SocketFactory that I found on this blog post:
https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/

and using it like so:

```
fun getHttpClientBuilder(enableLogging: Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG, vararg customInterceptors: Interceptor): OkHttpClient.Builder {
    val timeoutSecs = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else TIMEOUT_SECONDS_RELEASE
    val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(timeoutSecs.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(timeoutSecs.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(timeoutSecs.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectionSpecs(listOf(ConnectionSpec.RESTRICTED_TLS)) //  Restrict to TLS 1.2 and 1.3

    for (customInterceptor in customInterceptors) {
        httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(customInterceptor)
    }

    val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logger.level = if (enableLogging) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logger)

    return httpClientBuilder
}

fun buildHttpClient(enableLogging: Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG, vararg customInterceptors: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return getHttpClientBuilder(enableLogging, *customInterceptors)
        .enableTls12() //This calls the custom socket factory
        .build()
}
```

The `enableTls12()` function call triggers this code:

```
  @JvmStatic
    fun OkHttpClient.Builder.enableTls12() = apply {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            try {
                val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2.javaName())
                sslContext.init(null, arrayOf(trustManager), null)

                sslSocketFactory(Tls12SocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory), trustManager)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error while setting TLS 1.2 compatibility:: ${e.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }
    }
```

So I think I have everything I need and this should be working.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try or what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @SharpEdge I used Conscrypt with a custom SocketFactory using this TrustManager: https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager/tree/master/src/de/duenndns/ssl

Answer (score 0):

Similiar problem to this link below, check on Tls12SocketFactory implementation 
 [Android 4.1 to 4.4 KitKat - Enable TLS 1.2 for API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202267/android-4-1-to-4-4-kitkat-enable-tls-1-2-for-api)

Comment: Thanks, but if you look in the `enableTls12()`  function, you'll see I'm using a `Tls12SocketFactory` which is the same one in that link.